# Mutate data across pages with SWR in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am using SWR in a NextJS project. I am fetching a list of data in my index page. In my create page I add a new entry to the data. Now I want to make use of SWR **mutate** to mutate the cached data and **don't** reload the list of data from the server.

This is possible in a single page/component. However, I can't do this in multiple pages because the data is automatically fetched from the server after I redirect to the index page.

What is currently happening: Fetch all data, redirect to create page, add single entry to the data, redirect to index, Fetch all data

What I want: Fetch all data, redirect to create page, add single entry to the data, redirect to index, data correctly displayed without refetch.

I made a simple demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-pike-gzoc3?file=/pages/create.js
I use `mutate("https://swapi.dev/api/people/", "New Name", false);` The `false` indicates that there should be no refetch. But it is not working.

Does anyone now how I can avoid the refetch with SWR mutate?

Comment: I think you need `revalidateOnMount: false`, and then you need to manually execute corresponding `mutate()` in a `React.useEffect()`

Answer (score 0):

In this example, an empty array is being used as the initial value and then is being mutated.

```js
  export const useSomething = () => {
  const { data } = useSWR(
    'dummy-key',
    async () => {
      return [];
    },
    {
      revalidateOnMount: !cache.get('dummy-key'),
      revalidateOnFocus: false,
      shouldRetryOnError: false,
    }
  );

  const setData = (data) => {
    mutate(
      'dummy-key',
      async (cacheData) => {
        return [...cacheData, data];
      },
      false
    );
  };

  return {
    data,
    setData,
  };
};
```